# How can I add records on an empty table

Tags: php, laravel

I have an empty table in my database in MySQL, and I trying to add multiple records

*`(I do this in this way because I'm following and order; If I delete a record then the auto increment field (id) skips 1 value. For example. I delete the id = 340 and then the following record start with an id with a value = 341)`*

I have an `If Else` statement in a function in my controller where I use to compare the `id` itself of my table **Hours**.

```
 public function showHours($id){

    $complex = ComplexNew::find($id);
    $fields = CourtsComplex::all();
    $hours = HoursNew::all();

    $last_hours = collect($hours)->last();

    if ($last_hours->id == $last_hours->id){

        $last_hours->id = $last_hours->id + 1;
    }else{

        return Redirect()->back();
    }
    return view('hours.FormNewHours')->with('complex', $complex)->with('fields', $fields)->with('last_hours', $last_hours);
}
```

And this line is the line where I have the error.

```
if ($last_hours->id == $last_hours->id){
    //DO SOMETHING
    // ...
}
```

> The error is: **`'Trying to get property 'id' of non-object'`.**

Also I was trying to add another if else statement something like this:

```
if(is_null($last_hours->id)){

    $last_hours->id = 1;
}else if($last_hours->id == $last_hours->id){

    //ADD +1 TO ID.
}
```

Because I want that if the table is empty the id of the first record must be started with value = 1 but if the table is not empty add 1 to the last id, like a for statement because this condition add always +1 to last id.

Comment: Can you `dd($last_hours);` ? What it returns?

Comment: There's no need to make `$hours` a Collection. It's already one. That being said, what's going on here: `$last_hours->id == $last_hours->id`, this will always evaluate to true?

Comment: I have already tested with dd($last_hours); and it returned a null value.

Comment: Why do you care about if the IDs skipping some numbers?

Comment: @M4uriXD check my update answer please.

Comment: IMO, auto-increment should not guarantee a sequence without gaps. You should use SQL to find the next number; whatever that may be. Also, you said this is an empty table, right? So `$hours->last()` is going to be `null`. Maybe I'm missing something. Can you please clarify your question and design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$last_hours = collect($hours)->last();
```

to

```
$last_hours = $hours->last();
```

Plus `dd($last_hours)` if it returns **object** then try accessing `id` like `$last_hours->id`

Comment: Thanks you very much :) I do this and everything it solved after I corrected some minor errors.

Comment: Welcome glad to know :)

Comment: Your previous answer it was also very useful.